# Bash script, string not replaced correctly with escaped $ and & characters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have created a shell script which takes a string as input. If the string contains `$` or `&`, then I need to replace those characters with `\$` and `\&`. I could done that with `sed` command. After this I want to replace a word in a particular text file with that corresponding string.

Please see this section for more clarification.

This is my file.

```
test.txt

hello my root password is root.
```

Now, I want to change the word root with a string. The string can be anything which may include special characters like `$` or `&`.

If I want to replace `root` with the string `my&rootpa$$`, then it should look like `my\&rootpa\$\$` in text file.

This is my shell scipt

```
#!/bin/bash
dothis(){
    rootpass=$(echo "$1" | sed -r 's/\$/\\$/g');
    rootpass=$(echo "$rootpass" | sed -r 's/\&/\\&/g');
    echo $rootpass;
    sed -i "s/root/$rootpass/g" test.txt
}
dothis "my&rootpa$$";
```

This script works properly upto `echo $rootpass`, which means when I echo the string it will display `my\&rootpa\$\$`.

But in the file it looks `my&rootpa$$` instead of `my\&rootpa\$\$`. What's wrong with the script?

Please advice.

Comment: Please don't cross port to multiple SE sites. I see you have an answer on [SU] that is correct though.

Comment: Hi lain, I have posted the same question at SuperUser, askubuntu also. I was in a bit hurry to get the answer. Is there any issues in this ?

Comment: Yes, please don't do it as it fragments the answers and is frowned upon. Also as you found out you can make errors when copying them which is a nuisance. Just don't do it.

Comment: Thanks Lain for your concern. I am beginner in all these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an extra layer of quoting lacking.  In sed `&` has a special meaning in the replacement (stands for the matching string).  So to insert a literal `&` you'd escape it once, and to insert a literal `\&`, you'd escape the backslash (`\\`) and the ampersand (`\\&`), same for the backslash before `$`.  That gives you:

```
#!/bin/bash
dothis(){
    rootpass="${1//\$/\\\\$}"
    rootpass="${rootpass//&/\\\\\&}"
    echo $rootpass
    sed -i "s/root/$rootpass/g" test.txt
}
dothis 'my&rootpa$$';
```

Comment: Not working for me: `${$1//&/\\\\\&}: bad substitution`

Answer (score 0):

You should change this line:

```
dothis "my&rootpa$$";
```

to

```
dothis "my&rootpa\$\$";
```

or using quote instead of double quotes:

```
dothis 'my&rootpa$$';
```

In your case, `$$` in string `my&rootpa$$` will be expanded to PID of script itself.

Comment: As the OP says everything OK up to the last sed command at which point $rootpass is `my\&rootpas\$\$` so the problem variable expansion.

Answer (score 0):

This "`dothis "my&rootpa$$"` uses [double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) and the "`$$`" at the end will be expanded to the current PID. When I execute your script, this happens:

```
 $ ./a.sh 
 my\&rootpa3595
```

...since "3595" happens to be the PID of the script. When you use single quotes (' '), the string you expected is printed:

```
 $ tail -1 a.sh 
 dothis 'my&rootpa$$';

 $ ./a.sh 
 my\&rootpa\$\$
```

Comment: Note the last paragraph of the question which show that the $$ isn't being expanded...  Take a look at revision 1 of the OPs question it shows an incorrect sed command, I suspect other transcription errors too.

Comment: NOte also that you haven't done the final sed which is the problem.